# Many to Many relationship :through giving 'Could not find the association' error

Tags: ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

In my model an `Item` is created by a `User` and can be purchased by many `Users`, and a `User` can purchase many `Items`.

`User`, `Item`, and `Purchase` are defined, using `AcvtiveRecord` *with superfluous details snipped for brevity* as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # various other fields
  has_many :items, :foreign_key => :creator_id
  has_many :purchased_items, :through => :purchases, :source => :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  # various other fields
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :buyers, :through => :purchases, :source => :user
 end

 class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item
   belongs_to :user
  # various other fields
 end
```

and an `rspec` test *also snipped* as follows:

```
describe "user purchasing" do
  it "should allow a user to purchase an item" do
    a_purchase = Purchase.create!(:item => @item, # set up in `before :each`
                                  :user => @user  # set up in `before :each`
    )
    a_purchase.should_not eq(nil)                 # passes
    @item.buyers.should include @user             # fails
    @user.purchased_items.should include @item    # fails
  end
end
```

This results in

```
1) Purchase user purchasing should allow a user to purchase an item
   Failure/Error: @item.buyers.should include @user
   ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError:
     Could not find the association :purchases in model Item
```

Likewise if I swap around `@file_item.buyers.should include @user` and `@user.purchased_items.should include @item` I get the equivalent

```
1) Purchase user purchasing should allow a user to purchase an item
   Failure/Error: @user.purchased_items.should include @item
   ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError:
     Could not find the association :purchases in model User
```

My `migration` looks like

```
create_table :users do |t|
  # various fields
end

create_table :items do |t|
  t.integer :creator_id   # file belongs_to creator, user has_many items
  # various fields
end

create_table :purchases do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :item_id
  # various fields
end
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Wat happens if you remove `, :source => :item` in both User and Item ?

Comment: Good question. I just tried that and it made not a skerrick of difference. I still get `Could not find the association :purchases in model Item` (or vice-versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the following.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :items, :foreign_key => :creator_id
  has_many :purchased_items, :through => :purchases, :source => :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  # various other fields
  has_many :purchases
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :buyers, :through => :purchases, :source => :user
end
```

Only when you specify

```
      has_many :purchases
```

the model will be able to identify the association.